# What material is it? (Holdout node)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view

I got an asset from internet to make cool cards, they have 2 layers, the first one is for object and the second for the card it self. And my question is: What material it is? Does this material just work in Eevee?

[image: screenshot of the card]

...because when I use the Cycles render engine it doesn't work, it's just black
[image: Cycles render]

In the shader editor there is just a "Holdout" node.

[image: node editor]

Comment: Try looking here - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html - Maybe they meant for the card to be rendered in 2 separate layers and then composited together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Holdout* node creates alpha transparency, in Eevee it looks like you don't need to activate anything but in Cycles you need to enable the *Render > Film > Transparent* option to make it work:

[image]